# When is Type.GetMember ambiguous?

Tags: c#, reflection

When calling `Type.GetMember(string name, MemberTypes type, BindingFlags bindingAttr)`, when is this information not enough to find zero or one members, assuming `bindingAttr` is `BindingFlags.Default` (i.e. Doesn't matter). What kinds of members will need to be indivdually disambiguated through other properties?

Comment: I think it can find all members (see [GetMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1dk6tw7k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))... Or you are asking when it returns more than 1?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple overrides will return multiple results:

```
 class X
 {
      public int GetX(){ return 1;}
      public int GetX(string s){ return 2;}
 }

var r =  typeof(X).GetMember("GetX", MemberTypes.Method, 
        BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public); // 2 items
```

Note that specifying `Default` will always return 0 items - you need at least `Instance` or `Static`. See [Type.GetMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1dk6tw7k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.

Comment: @AlexiLevenkov So all other members can be adressed by name other than methods? What about property accessors?

Comment: @AlphaModder I'd expect shadowing with `new` will cause similar problem - just try. I don't know all cases.